# Why does removing '\n' from my fgets buffer cause my program to crash?

Tags: c, string

I'm currently trying to import an array of "Libro" (Book) structs from a txt file. The file in question is structured in the following way for every entry:

```
titolo
editore
prezzo
anno
```

so I'm getting the string with the fget function, and trying to delete the '\n' at the end. Issue is, removing the '\n' causes my program to stop functioning.

```
#include "libro.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

Libro* get_biblioteca(char path[], int size){
    char buff[255];

    char titolo[255];
    char editore[255];
    float prezzo;

    int curr = 0;
    int c_lib = 0;

    Libro *biblioteca = malloc(sizeof(Libro)*size); 
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
    while (fgets(buff, 255, fp)!=NULL){
        int size = strnlen(buff, 255);
        if (buff[size-1]=='\n')
            {
                buff[size-1]='\0';  //<---- if you remove this, it works, but it keeps the \n
                printf(">%s<", buff);
            }

        if (curr == 0)
            strcpy(titolo, buff);

        if (curr == 1)
            strcpy(editore, buff);
        
        if (curr == 2)
            prezzo = atof(buff);

        if (curr == 3){
            biblioteca[c_lib]=crea_libro(titolo, editore, prezzo, atoi(buff));
            c_lib++;
            curr = 0;
        } 
        else
            curr++;
    }
    return biblioteca;
}

int main(void){
    Libro *biblio = get_biblioteca("test.txt", 5);

    print_libro(biblio[3]);
}
```

This is the header file for reference:

```
typedef struct opaque_libro *Libro;

Libro crea_libro (char titolo[], char editore[], float prezzo, int anno);
```

and this is libro.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "libro.h"

typedef struct opaque_libro {
    char *titolo;
    char *editore;
    float prezzo;
    int anno;
} opaque_libro;

Libro crea_libro (char titolo[], char editore[], float prezzo, int anno){
    int size = strlen(titolo);
    
    Libro new = malloc(sizeof(Libro));
        if (new == NULL) return NULL;

    new->titolo = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
        if (new->titolo == NULL) return NULL;
    
    size = strlen(editore);
    new ->editore = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
        if (new->editore == NULL) return NULL;
    
    new->prezzo = prezzo;
    new->anno = anno;

    strcpy(new->titolo, titolo);
    strcpy(new->editore, editore);

    return new;
}

void print_libro (Libro lib){
    printf("titolo: %s\neditore: %s\nprezzo: %.2f\nanno: %d\n", lib->titolo, lib->editore, lib->prezzo, lib->anno);
}
```

and for the sake of debugging, this is test.txt:

```
Up
Down
20.5
1999
Gran
Canyon
22
1998
Junji
Ito
24
1864
Current
Emergencies
1.20
2024
Left
Down
90
2024
```

I even tried using a for loop, strcspn, but to no avail. I'm genuinely curious what's the issue at this point.

Comment: [There are better ways to remove the newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input?rq=2).

Comment: `new->titolo = malloc(size * sizeof(char));` doesn't allocate space for the terminating 0. Use `(size + 1)`.

Comment: On a different note, you *know* that the length of the string in `buff` will not be longer than 254 characters. That's because it's the size guaranteed by `fgets`. You don't need the non-standard `strnlen` call to get the length, you can use plain `strlen`.

Comment: Why ignore the return value of `fopen()`?

Comment: @Maridiama, `if (buff[size-1]=='\n')` fails (UB) in the rare case where the first character _read_ is a _null character_.  Avoid this  hacker exploitable code.

Comment: Oh and while a loop might seem natural for things that needs to be done multiple times, when you do totally different things inside the loop depending on loop value, then perhaps a loop is not the right thing to do. I suggest you break out the only repetitive thing (the use of `fgets`) into its own function, then call that function three times without the loop. Pass `titolo` and `editore` as arguments for the first two calls, and use a temporary buffer for the numeric input.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I already explained in the post, I used `buff[strcspn(buff, "\n")] = 0;` but it didn't solve the issue.

@RetiredNinja has the actual answer here